# Prove that a graph with 4n vertices and n edges can be transformed into another with at least $(9n^2)$/4 triangles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, proof-explanation

Let $x$ be a vertex of a non-oriented graph $G$. The transformation
$\phi(x)$ of $G$ consists of deleting all edges incident with $x$ and drawing edges
$(x, y)$ for all vertices $y$ that were not joined to $x$ by an edge.  A graph
$H$ is said to be *$G$-obtainable* if it can be obtained from $G$ by a sequence of transformations of the above form. Let $n$ be a positive integer divisible by $4$.  Prove that for every graph $G$ with $4n$ vertices and $n$ edges there exists a $G$-obtainable graph containing at least $(9n^2)/4$ triangles.

I'm trying to follow the attempted solution posted [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h142946p809859); unfortunately, I can't understand the motivation behind the inequalities he presents. I'd appreciate it if someone help shed light on the author's arguments and also if this problem could be solved via Ramsey theory/ pigeonhole arguments.

Comment: It was from Bulgarian team selection test, 2007.